# How do I get information about a partition through the command line?

Tags: linux

On Ubuntu, I have the link to the partition (e.g. `/dev/sda1`). I want to know the labels, size,... of that partition.

How can I do that with a command in which the partition's link is a parameter? It is important to use this link in that command.

What about other devices?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Obviously Linux or a BSD variant...

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu :)

Comment: You can obviously `grep` results from the below commands for your specific label. E.g. `df -h | grep "/dev/sda1"`.

Comment: @slhck what about other info? for example label?

Answer (score 1):

```
df -h
fdisk -l
```

Will both give you different amounts of information on your mounted partitions.

Fdisk will give you more "physical" information like the heads and cylinder count. 
df will give you size information only.

Answer (score 0):

`dumpe2fs` will give you that information if it's an E2FS partition (probably works with ext3 too)

Answer (score 0):

```
fdisk -lu
```

in terms of sectors instead of cylinders.

See the man page for fdisk with the command:

```
man fdisk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e2label /dev/sda1; df /dev/sda1
```

The first part will tell you the label (if any, and assuming its an EXT2/3/4 filesystem), the second the size of the disk and related parameters.